# how to execute python file with codeigniter in PHP

Tags: php, python, codeigniter

I has use PHP to execute python file by use the code below.

```
<?php 
$a = shell_exec("echo 'root_password' | sudo -u root -S python turnon1.py");
echo $a;
?>
```

It's work very well in PHP Site 
but It didn't work for CI Framework.
I think the problem is about path of python file (CI can't find the file).How can i figures it out.

Python & php file is in same folder.

Thankyou for your helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the complete path to your python file.

```
$a = shell_exec("echo 'root_password' | sudo -u root -S python ".FCPATH."turnon1.py");
```

assuming python file is in same directory as index.php.